# Risotto and a complementing/contrasting broth corresponding to the meat

Tags: flavor, seafood, broth, risotto

In most recipes I've found, risotto calls for a chicken broth, but if I'm making a seared halibut on top of risotto, for example, or a seared scallop risotto, shouldn't the broth be a seafood broth to complement the seafood meat atop the risotto, or is chicken broth the standard because of some reason that I don't know about?

Would the chicken broth contrast with a halibut or other seafood food in a positive way?

Does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a recipe for seafood risotto that used chicken broth. Commonly, clam juice or seafood stock is used. To me, chicken broth would clash. That seafood stock or clam juice is more common in seafood risotto recipes is confirmed by a [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=seafood%20risotto%20recipes).

Personally, I would never use chicken broth to make seafood risotto.

If I wanted a risotto to compliment seafood not actually in the risotto, I would also use a seafood based liquid.